# Cannot read property 'idToken' of undefined ionic Google android authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, ionic4, google-authentication

This was previously working...for some reason I had to remove and re-add either my IOS or Android platform.  At any rate, this is working for IOS but not Android.

I've created an Ionic 4 app and I've implemented Google and Facebook authentication.  They both work find on ios but for some reason I keep getting the below error for Google authentication for Android:

code causing error:

```js
  async googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
      console.log('before gPlus');
      return this.googlePlus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  }
```

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'idToken' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idToken' of undefined
    at AuthService.retrieveGoogleData
```

I've tried removing the platform, re-adding and removing the android firebase app and re-adding.  I even tried deleting my old WebClientId and creating a new one to no avail...I keep getting that error 10 and the idTOken is not being retrieved from Google.

I've tried several different ways of creating my key store per online discussions:

keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

and

keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

they both generate the same Sha1

Comment: what does this code snippet actually run?

Comment: That's not a code snippet, it's just the error that's caused by running this code:

return this.googlePlus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,

Comment: It's a console error

Comment: add that code to OP . it's better

Comment: Put the part where you want to get idToken .

Comment: It's in the GoogleLogin method I added.  This should return a token return this.googlePlus.login